# Remove or hide layers in geoPDF for PDF to TIFF conversion

Tags: arcpy, convert, geopdf

I'm using arcpy to convert a collection of maps in geoPDFs to geotiffs using the PDFtoTIFF conversion. There are several layers in the geopdf that I do not want included in the output geotiff for example; a graticule and coordinate layer.

I have tried to hide the visibility of the layer manually in the PDF, resave it, and then run the conversion.
I have also looked into trying to use PyPDF2 to help remove the layers but it does not seem the functionality exists with that module.
I have also looked into the PDFDocument methods for arcpy but it does not seem to have any functionality to hide or delete layers prior to exporting the map to PDF.

The code itself is basic but I need to be able to add functionality to programmatically remove or hide these layers for the output.

```
    i = r"...\889463821335_geo2.pdf"
    e = r"...\889463821335_geo2.tif"

    arcpy.PDFToTIFF_conversion(i,e,clip_option='CLIP_TO_MAP')
```